# Android NavigationView sub-menu header without items

Tags: android

I want to know if and how is possible to create a sub-menu header without items, like this:

[image]

```
 <item android:title="Sub items"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:title="Sub item 1" />
        <item
            android:title="Sub item 2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

If I use this it creates a sub-menu heading with two items (Sub item 1 and Sub item 2). I f I delete the subitems the header disappears to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **`menu_main.xml`** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate"
        android:id="@+id/communicate">

    </item>

</menu>
```

As you say you want to know if remove the `Sub Item` from the `item` then it is work as Normal like the upper 4 in my ScreenShot see the Output.

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: But I want it as sub-header not like a normal item

Comment: @tomss why you have require that type if your `Sub Header` is not contain any SubMenu..

Comment: I edit my question with an image. That is how I want my NavigationView. Thanks.

Comment: @tomss can you show me how much menu you have require Or either you can create custom menu..